# Which is the number of independent components of a flat spin connection in a 4 dimension Weitzenböck spacetime?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, mg.metric-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, mp.mathematical-physics

*A spin connection $A_{ab\mu}=-A_{ba\mu}$ has 24 components. The number of independent components for a flat spin connection can be counted by subtracting the constrains set by the condition of null curvature
\begin{equation}
R^a_{\phantom{a}b\mu\nu} = 0.
\end{equation}
The curvature tensor has at most 36 independent components. However, the second Bianchi identities 
\begin{equation}
D_{\rho}R^a_{\phantom{a}b\mu\nu} + D_{\mu}R^a_{\phantom{a}b\nu\rho} + D_{\nu}R^a_{\phantom{a}b\rho\mu} = 0
\end{equation}
with $D_{\mu}$ a Weitzenböck covariant derivative, sets 24 constrains in the components of the curvature, leaving only 12 independent. The first Bianchi identities 
\begin{equation}
D_{\rho}T^a_{\phantom{a}\mu\nu} + D_{\mu}T^a_{\phantom{a}\nu\rho} + D_{\nu}T^a_{\phantom{a}\rho\mu} = R^a_{\phantom{a}\rho\mu\nu} + R^a_{\phantom{a}\mu\nu\rho} + R^a_{\phantom{a}\nu\rho\mu}
\end{equation}
only sets constraints for the Torsion, so there are not additional constraints for the curvature.*

*The number of independent components of the flat spin connection, after subtracting the constrains, is 12.*

I can not be sure if this argument is complete and I cannot found help in the literature. I would appreciate feedback or a useful reference.

Thank for your help!